# how to change emacs meta key to apple command key when I use emacs installed on remote host through ssh connection?

Tags: emacs, ssh

I compiled GNU Emacs 23.2.1 on remote host but really want to use command key as the meta key in my terminal.app. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [cmd-key-happy](https://github.com/aim-stuff/cmd-key-happy/) to swap the command and option keys when using the terminal. This makes it possible to use the command key as a meta key in emacs.

Comment: cool~~ this is what I am looking for! How do you find this? You are wonderful~~